# ElasticSearch analyzer to match "Java", "Script" and "JavaScript"

Tags: elasticsearch

Indexed values: `Java, JavaScript, ClojureScript`.

```
_input_    | _output_
Java       | JavaScript, Java
JavaScript | JavaScript
script     | JavaScript, ClojureScript
```

The analyzer that most has been close to the wanted result is the following.

```
"analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "trigrams_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "3",
            "max_gram": "3"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "trigrams_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not accurate enough, as "JavaScript" returns "JavaScript" and "Java"
and "script" returns nothing.

Comment: Have you specyfied any mapping for your type?

Comment: @Adam yes. I'm working on a manually-mapped type which contains an array of strings `skills` mapped as `type: string` / `analyzer: trigrams`

Comment: Ok I have already solved your problem (I will publish the answear in few minutes) but the question is about stored data. Do you store always PascalCase words like JavaScript, Java? I'm asking because if you store always PascalCase words and you want to search only by part of the word like Pascal or Case then I can provide you a better approach.

Comment: I don't have control on these values as they are created by users and this is reason why I'm using the `lowercase` filter.

Comment: So you need to use what I described in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one main problem with your mapping: You want to use edge_ngram filter to search part of a word. Edge_ngram filter is used when you want to find words that start with a query value. In your case you should use nGram filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html

Additionally you should only specify trigrams analyser when data are index. For searching it's better to use a standard analyser because there is no sense to put query string through nGram filter because you will get more data than you need.

Correct mapping:

```
POST /so
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "trigrams_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": "2",
               "max_gram": "20"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "trigrams": {
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "trigrams_filter"
               ],
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "so" :{
           "properties": {
               "text": {
                   "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "trigrams",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Values:

```
POST /so/so/1
{
    "text" :"Java"
}
POST /so/so/2
{
    "text" :"JavaScript"
}
POST /so/so/3
{
    "text" :"ClojureScript"
}
```

When your query string is “java” then response contains: Java and JavaScript

```
POST /so/so/_search
{
    "query": {"match": {
       "text": "Java"
    }}
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "so",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "Java"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "so",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "JavaScript"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When your query string is “JavaScript” then response contains: JavaScript

```
POST /so/so/_search
{
    "query": {"match": {
       "text": " JavaScript "
    }}
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "so",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "text": "JavaScript"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When your query string is “script” then response contains: JavaScript and ClojureScript

```
POST /so/so/_search
{
    "query": {"match": {
       "text": "script"
    }}
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "so",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "JavaScript"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so",
            "_type": "so",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "ClojureScript"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```